# grep command is not retrieving complete function

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep word `to_char()` from the file with the command `grep -E -o -i "TO_CHAR\(+..[^)]+\)"` , but am couldn't get complete function

```
TO_CHAR(123)
TO_CHAR(NVL(B.DATE,SYSDATE)
TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(AMT,0)
```

A file contains the following lines:

```
TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
to_char(aaa) 
TO_CHAR('asc')
```

I need to select words that do not contain a comma. It should fetch only `to_char(aaa)` and `TO_CHAR('asc')` and it should not select `TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` since it has a comma.

I have tried using:

```
TO_CHAR(.[^,)]*)
```

but it is selecting `TO_CHAR(DATE`.

Comment: Is the line starting with TO_CHAR(123) is the file you want to grep?  Are you aiming to detect TO_CHAR() with any number of characters between the parentheses?  If so, wouldn't `grep -E TO_CHAR\(.*\) *` be sufficient?

Comment: am having lines in a file as below  as TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') to_char(aaa) TO_CHAR('asc') , here i need to select words which does not contain , (comma). it should fetch only to_char(aaa)  and TO_CHAR('asc') , it should not select TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') since it has ,(comma) . i used TO_CHAR\(.[^,\)]*\) but it is selecting TO_CHAR(DATE this.

Comment: Don't add examples and statements of requirements in comments where they can't be formatted and could be missed, [edit] your question to contain all relevant information. In particular - add the expected output for the sample input you provide.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not clear, but going by the further information you have provided in the comments, it seems that you are trying to match strings that do not include a comma `,` within the parenthesis `()`?

If my assumption is correct, then this grep code should be able to extract the match.

```
grep -E '.*\(.[^,]*\)' input_file
```

**Input**

```
TO_CHAR(123)
TO_CHAR(NVL(B.DATE,SYSDATE)
TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(AMT,0)TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
to_char(aaa)
TO_CHAR('asc')
```

**Output**

```
TO_CHAR(123)
to_char(aaa)
TO_CHAR('asc')
```